# Bipartite graph using union find algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite

How can i check if a disconnected graph is bipartite or not using disjoint set?
I was solving [A Bugs Life](https://www.spoj.com/problems/BUGLIFE/) I recently solved using dfs,But most of the people were also commenting  that they solved using union find algorithm.
So I am curious how can i solve it using union find ?

Note -> we just have to check if the graph is Bipartite or not in the problem

It will be better if you can provide the implementation in cpp